# can i use an object property value, as a css property value?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have an object with a property who's value will be changing repeatedly.
Along with that i need the value of a css property to mirror the objects property value. 
below is my javascript function that will be executing this along with other things...

```
const initStats = () => {
stats();



let uD = document.querySelector("#defense")
  let uSp= document.querySelector("#speed")
  let uSt = document.querySelector("#strength")
  let uHth = document.querySelector("#health")

  uD.textContent = "Defense: " + fighterUser.defense
  let width = fighterUser.defense
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.classList.add('content');
  content.style.width = fighterUser.defense
  uD.appendChild(content);


  uSp.textContent = "speed: " + fighterUser.speed
  uSt.textContent = "Strength: " + fighterUser.strength
  uHth.textContent = "health: " + fighterUser.health


  let cD = document.querySelector("#defense-cpu")
  let cSp= document.querySelector("#speed-cpu")
  let cSt = document.querySelector("#strength-cpu")
  let cHth = document.querySelector("#health-cpu")

  cD.textContent = "Defense: " + fighterCpu.defense
  cSp.textContent = "Speed: " + fighterCpu.speed
  cSt.textContent = "Strength: " + fighterCpu.strength
  cHth.textContent = "health: " + fighterCpu.health
}
```

this is the section i need help with, i am attempting to do something like this but i know css will not take "fighterUser.defense" as a value...

```
uD.textContent = "Defense: " + fighterUser.defense
  let width = fighterUser.defense
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.classList.add('content');
  content.style.width = fighterUser.defense
  uD.appendChild(content);
```

thank all!

Comment: How come you don't want to use a variable that stores a simple number? `var hp =38` or an obj.property: `var bezerker = {hp:-10}`

Comment: The reason being that I am experimenting and wanting to create a horizontal bar graph under each stat. The percentage will vary/ change many times, hope i explained myself ?

Comment: A **[`<meter>` tag](https://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/)** is used for known quantities like a car's top speed 130.

Comment: Well the meter tag work within a range? @zer00ne

Comment: Click the link and read the article you should find that answer at the end of it I think.

Comment: Thank you I’m going to look further into meter and see if I can use it thanks again @zer00ne

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'px' or a '%' relative to the parent node and indicate that the value can be measured:

```
content.style.width = fighterUser.defense + 'px'
```